# Ubuntu stuck on login screen and it goes black

Tags: 12.04, installation

I recently install the latest version of Ubuntu and it went perfect. Since that is stuck in login screen and I can't even type anything from keyboard and use my mouse to do something. Then after 5 minutes, it does black like its in idea mode and stay as same condition for while. I have to turn it off manually and on to get to my home screen or login screen.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and <kbd>e</kbd> key but nothing works. Please, help me out.

And I would like to install Windows XP instead of Ubuntu, is it possible to install in this mode, I tried once but does not work so, I think I need to start Ubuntu first then I could install Windows XP?

Comment: Well, you don't need to be inside the system to install Windows XP, just start it at boot. <joke>Although I don't recommend anyone on installing windows XP</joke>

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's not reading your keyboard or mouse. If you can't even bring up the first TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then it sounds like your inputs are not being picked up at all.

What kind of keyboard/mouse are you using? Standard USB/PS2 or bluetooth/wireless?

Comment: Ya m using standard usb one, and i got into recovery mode and no idea wht to do, i tried many form. i dont knw what to write at where? And ya my keyboard works in that situation.